# Como mockar um objeto constante no Jest

Tags: typescript, jest

Olá tenho tenho um arquivo de constantes definido assim em um projeto React:

`src/constants/env.ts`

```js
export default {
   PROD: ['prod', 'production'].includes((process.env.NODE_ENV || '').toLowerCase())
}
```

Esse arquivo é usado pra definir algumas configurações como no exemplo abaixo:

`src/utils/storage/Storage.ts`

```js
import ENV from 'src/constants/env'

class Storage {
  async get<T = any>(key: string): Promise<T | undefined> {
    return await new Promise((resolve) => {
      try {
        let value = localStorage.getItem(key) as string
        if (value) {
          if (ENV.PROD) value = btoa(value)
          resolve(JSON.parse(value) as any as T)
        }
      } catch (error) { }
      resolve(undefined)
    })
  }

  async set(key: any, value: any): Promise<void> {
    return await new Promise((resolve) => {
      try {
        value = JSON.stringify(value)
        if (ENV.PROD) value = atob(value)
        localStorage.setItem(key, value)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
      }
      resolve()
    })
  }
}

export default new Storage()
```

E estou tentando mockar o valor de `PROD` como `true` para que a classe Storage leia o ENV como true e então salve os dados em base64.

`src/utils/storage/Storage.test.ts`

```js
import Storage from './Storage'
import ENV from 'src/constants/env'

describe('Storage', () => {
  const key = 'test'
  const value = { test: 'test' }

  const { PROD } = ENV

  beforeEach(() => {
    localStorage.clear()
    ENV.PROD = false
  })

  afterAll(() => ENV.PROD = PROD)

  describe('set', () => {
    test('should set encoded base64 data if prod mode', async () => {
      ENV.PROD = true
      await Storage.set(key, value)
      expect(localStorage.getItem(key)).toEqual(atob(JSON.stringify(value)))
    })
  })
})
```

Mas não estou conseguindo fazer com que a classe Storage leia o valor de PROD como true. O que é necessário para fazer o mock deste arquivo de constantes? Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Talvez possa ajudar: [Manual Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks).

Comment: Não vi nenhum lugar na documentação que me permitisse mockar esse arquivo de constantes... alguma outra idéia

Answer (score 0):

Conforme sugeri nos comentários, você pode optar por utilizar os [*manual mocks*](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks).

#### Utilizando *manual mocks*

Basicamente, você poderia criar, dentro do diretório do recurso que você está importando, um outro diretório chamado `__mocks__`, onde você cria um arquivo de mesmo nome daquele que você está importando.

Vamos tentar entender através de um exemplo:

```
.
├── babel.config.js
├── jest.config.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── __tests__
│   │   └── util.js
│   ├── constants
│   │   ├── __mocks__
│   │   └── env.js
│   ├── index.js
│   └── util.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

Onde `src/index.js` corresponde a:

```js
import { getAppEnvironment } from './util';

(function() {
  console.log(getAppEnvironment());
})();
```

`src/util.js` corresponde a:

```js
import ENV from './constants/env';

export function getAppEnvironment() {
  return ENV.PRODUCTION ? 'Production' : 'Development';
}
```

E `src/constants/env.js`:

```js
export default {
  PRODUCTION: ["prod", "production"].includes((process.env.NODE_ENV || '').toLowerCase())
}
```

Da mesma forma que no seu caso.

---

Então, quando vou fazer o teste em `src/__tests__/util.js`, eu faço:

```js
jest.mock('../constants/env');

const { getAppEnvironment } = require("../util");

describe("Testing the consistency of the environment teller", () => {
  it("should return 'Production' when it's on production", () => {
    require('../constants/env').__setEnvironmentData('PRODUCTION', true);

    let environment = getAppEnvironment();

    expect(environment).toBe('Production');
  });

  it("should return 'Development' when it's on development", () => {
    require('../constants/env').__setEnvironmentData('PRODUCTION', false);

    let environment = getAppEnvironment();

    expect(environment).toBe('Development');
  })
});
```

Note que, antes de importar a função `getAppEnvironment`, e [isso principalmente se eu estivesse utilizando um `import`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#using-with-es-module-imports), eu utilizo o [método `jest.mock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options), para que o módulo `constants/env` a ser importado, seja o módulo *mockado* (contido em `constants/__mocks__`), e não o módulo original.

Mas, mesmo se você não fizer o *mocking* antes da importação, de acordo com a documentação, o próprio Jest cuidará de fazê-lo.

---

Aí, pode-se pensar: *espera, que coisa estranha é aquela?*

```js
    require('../constants/env').__setEnvironmentData('PRODUCTION', true);
```

Isso é uma função, **presente no módulo *mockado***, que estaremos utilizando para alterar o valor da "constante" `PRODUCTION` para aquilo que quisermos. E aqui está o código do módulo *mockado*:

```js
const data = { PRODUCTION: false };

export function __setEnvironmentData(key, value) {
  data[key] = value;
}

export default data;
```

Onde eu, simplesmente, atribuo um objeto a `data`, que corresponderá ao objeto que seria retornado pelo módulo original, e defino a função `__setEnvironmentData`, que, conforme dito antes, será a responsável por modificar o valor da "constante".

Com isso tudo, podemos perceber que o responsável por importar o módulo `constants/env` (claro, durante os testes) será o próprio Jest, pois, será ele o responsável por trocar o módulo original pelo *mock*, esse o qual permitirá a troca do valor da "constante".

#### Executando os testes

Vamos executar os testes:

```
device:481942 gustavosampaio$ npm test

> so-question-481942@0.1.0 test /path/to/SO/481942
> jest

 PASS  src/__tests__/util.js
  Testing the consistency of the environment teller
    ✓ should return 'Production' when it's on production (1 ms)
    ✓ should return 'Development' when it's on development

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.009 s
Ran all test suites.
device:481942 gustavosampaio$
```

Conseguimos fazer o *mock* do módulo!

E se quiser atestar que realmente é isso, tente comentar o `jest.mock` e depois as chamadas da função `__setEnvironmentData`. :)

---

Lembrando que, no meu caso, só foi possível utilizar [a sintaxe `import` do ES](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), através do Webpack e do Babel! ;)